# Android Swipe Fragment on click

Tags: java, android, fragment, swipe

I have a Fragment pager, I built a button on the first fragment.
Now I want to make it swipe to the second fragment when I click on that button.
I built this so far:

```
public class HowTo extends Fragment {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.how_to, container, false);
            ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.howTo)).setText("howto");

                Button next_frag = (Button) android.findViewById(R.id.next_frag);
                next_frag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Swipe to page`?
                        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.how_to, container, false);

                    }
                });
            return android;

        }


}
```

It did not work. Does anyone know how to solve this issue.

EDIT:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And xml with my button that is going to change fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/how_to_gradient">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="test"
        android:background="@drawable/border_inner_orange"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this on Button Click:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextposition);
```

or if you want a smooth scroll you can use

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,true);
```

**Edit:**

You can get the Current page of View pager by :

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

get the number & add +1 to put the value in nextposition

**EDITED:**

**MainActivity:**

inside MainActivity initialize a static instance of MainActivity:

```
public static MainActivity mInstance = null;
```

then inside onCreate method of MainActivity do like this:

```
mInstance = this;
```

these above are two additions in your MainActivity..

```
Now Your Fragment

public class HowTo extends Fragment {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.how_to, container, false);
            ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.howTo)).setText("howto");

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) MainActivity.mInstance.findViewById(R.id.pager);

int nextFragment = viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;

                Button next_frag = (Button) android.findViewById(R.id.next_frag);
                next_frag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Swipe to page`?

viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextFragment);

                    }
                });
            return android;

        }
}
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {

                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position,true);

                    } does not work

Comment: you have a view pager & show different Fragment when u swipe right ? Then on button click you just have to change the current position of your view pager by using viewPager.setCurrentItem(nextposition);

Comment: I cannot do that I cannot use findviewbyid inside of a Fragment that works only inside of Activitys

Comment: Can you edit your answer with that code looks confusing like that

Comment: NICE IT WORKED:) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To Make Fragments on Swipe you can use ViewPager

or

Try this to Swipe on Click

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I have an viewpager swipe works as well. I just want to go to the next fragment if I click on my button.