# Detecting Swipe In Viewpager Under Button -

Tags: android, fragment

Does anyone know how to make a viewpager respond to drags/swipes even when someone's finger is on a button within the view pager? I've attempted to override OnTouch (which isn't even being hit when I use breakpoints) and I've tried adding the fragment's touchables to the View Pager's touchables. Both to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Are the views Overlapping each other ?

Comment: As in, are the buttons on the viewpager? If so, then yes. I'll add a picture.

Comment: If u swipe over this Orange area, the touch Listener will not work for the view behind, because TouchListener works from top to bottom

Comment: I'm looking to have the orange area move even when the user's finger is on a button while swiping. My apologies if I was not clear.

Comment: you want to change the fragment on swipe ?

Comment: The red/orange area is a viewpager, if you swipe it to the right it shows six more buttons. My problem is it won't swipe if the user's finger is on a button.

Comment: just one more question.. those six buttons are on this same fragment's layout under the viewPager or they are on the next fragment's layout under viewPager ?

Comment: They're on another fragment layout.

Comment: I have answered somthing a bit similar, what you have to change is do this on button's ontouch when move.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681273/android-swipe-fragment-on-click/32681367#32681367

Comment: Roger that. Thanks for the info, I'll look into it.

Comment: If it help you do upvote that answer. If you found any issue leave the comment will look that tomorrow

Comment: Did you find your answer ?

Comment: I have not, unfortunately. The client wasn't worried about it, and I've got another project I'm working on so I'll come back to it when I start doing android development again. It's definitely something I'd like to know how to do.